# Missing Gemfile.lock on creation of rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, gemfile

While creating a Rails application:

```
user$ rails new App
```

All the other files get created, i.e. `app, config, db, doc, script, test, Gemfile, etc` I find that the `Gemfile.lock` fails to be created. Any particular reason why this could be happening? I am facing errors in bundling gems, though I do not know whether the absence of the `Gemfile.lock` file is causing this. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

you dont get a lock until after you do your bundle, and whenever there is a well form group of gems built (with all dependancies available..)

if you run:

`bundle install`

I think one should get created for you.

or

`bundle update`

if you have a lock file and have an updated gemset

Comment: ...assuming that your have all your gems in order! :)

Comment: a back trace might shine some light on your bundling problem if thats the issue your encountering..

Comment: No Problem! dont forget to accept the answer :) http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png